# Keras - Custom layer with multiple inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I would like to implement a custom `tf.keras` layer called `MyLayer` which has three inputs and contains a sub layer which in turn has three inputs, like in the figure below:

[image: MyLayer]

I assume that the right thing to do would be to create a `MyLayer` class that extends `tf.keras.layers.Layer` and implement the `__init__`, `build` and `call` methods, as mentioned in the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models).

Now, the examples provided in the documentation are relative to pretty simple layers that are composed of several sublayers connected in a sequential manner, that is one after the other. For instance, the [`MLPBlock`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models#layers_are_recursively_composable) layer consists of 3 linear layers ordered sequentially.

In general, however, sublayers are not ordered sequentially, but can form branches. This suggests that those layers could be run in parallel, since they are not connected to one another.
Going back to the custom layer I would like to implement, you can see that `Layer1`, `Layer2` and `Layer3` could be run in parallel. Once their outputs are computed, they can be fed to `Layer4`. The point is: how do I run them in parallel? I couldn't find any "ParallelCombinator" or things like that among the [available Keras layers](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers).

If I were to follow the examples provided in the documentation, I would write something along these lines:

```py
class MyLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(MyLayer, self).__init__()
        self.layer_1 = Layer1(...)
        self.layer_2 = Layer2(...)
        self.layer_3 = Layer3(...)
        self.layer_4 = Layer4(...)

    def call(self, inputs):
        tmp_1 = self.layer_1(inputs[0])
        tmp_2 = self.layer_2(inputs[1])
        tmp_3 = self.layer_3(inputs[2])
        return self.layer4([tmp_1, tmp_2, tmp_3])
```

This, however, would imply that `Layer1`, `Layer2` and `Layer3` are run sequentially, not in parallel.

One possible solution that I came up with involves structuring `MyLayer` as a `tf.keras.Model` built with Keras's functional API rather than as a subclass of `tf.keras.Layer`, like so:

```py
def MyLayer(...):
    input_1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(...)
    input_2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(...)
    input_3 = tf.keras.layers.Input(...)

    layer_1 = Layer1(...)(input_1)
    layer_2 = Layer2(...)(input_2)
    layer_3 = Layer3(...)(input_3)
    output_1 = Layer4(...)([layer_1, layer_2, layer_3])

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2, input_3], outputs=output_1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_layer = MyLayer(...)
    input_1 = ...
    input_2 = ...
    input_3 = ...
    output = my_layer([input_1, input_2, input_3])
```

The reason why I think this would work is that I assume that when I feed some inputs to a `tf.keras.Model`, as in `output = my_layer([input_1, input_2, input_3])`, the layers that *can* be run in parallel are effectively run in parallel (or are they?). This solution, however, feels like a hack to me, as `MyLayer` is supposed to be a layer, *not* a model. In fact, a `tf.keras.Model` instance exposes methods like `fit(...)` that aren't meant to be called on a layer.

Does anybody know what's the best approach to implement `MyLayer`?